# Why does list index -0 form an empty list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Imagine a list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

where you simply want to iterate and print slices from this list by:

```
for i in range(len(a)-2):
    print(a[2: -i])
```

This yields:

```
[]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4]
[3]
```

Here, I note that specifying a list index as `a[2: -0]` returns an empty list.
I would have thought this would have returned all the numbers from index 2 upwards.
Is there a simple explanation for this behaviour?

Returning to the example where the desired result would be:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4]
[3]
```

The introduction of an `if` statement seems like a clumsy way to treat this problem. Such as:

```
for i in range(len(a)-2):
    if i == 0:
        print(a[2:])
    else:
        print(a[2:-i])
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: As far as i can perceive that for python it doesn't matters whether it is 0 or -0 hence     `a[2 : -0]`  is rephrased as `a[2 : 0]` which in fact is an empty list

Comment: Indeed, for integers `-0` *is* `0`. Floats have an separate value for `-0.0`, but you can't use floats for indexing lists.

Comment: >>> -0 == 0
True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to work around the issue, that `-0` is `0`, which puts it at the wrong end of the list for your intended slicing.

One option is as Vishal Dhawan has proposed, to substitute `None` for the `-0` value. That works because `None` in a slice means "keep slicing until the end of the list".

Another option would be to do the math yourself for the indexes, rather than using negative indexes to count from the end. You'd want `a[2:len(a)-i]`.

The best option is to change the `range` you're looping over so that it directly gives you the slice-end index you want, without any additional math being needed. Danil Melnikov's answer almost does this, but it has some errors with its `range` call, so it produces the wrong output. Try:

```
for i in range(len(a), 2, -1):
    print(a[2: i])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(len(a)-2):
    print(a[2: -i or None])
```

This can make it look neat. But as suggested by @Akshat2249 a[2:0] should return nothing.

Comment: Another option is to do the index math yourself, rather than using negatives: `a[2:len(a)-i]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for i in range(len(a)-1, 0, -1):
    print(a[2: i])
```

Would give:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4]
[3]
```

When you work with list slice it has logic like start from 2 and reach 0, but if start point > finish point the loop is over, we can specify the step, -1 or +1 [2:0:-1]

Comment: Your `range` isn't quite right. You want `range(len(a), 2, -1)`, or you'll skip the first output you want, and add two extra empty slices at the end.